# Dapp Lag Caused By Fetch Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello eyeryone I made a decentrelized raffle game on Binance chain. I am able to read data or execute functions from Dapp very well. But I am facing with a LAG when I try to call many function from Smart Contract. Actually I just call 10 function which is not much. As my experience, when I put console.log() for each function I see its fetching data too many times in a short time.

For example: At first it fetches normally, when it pass the "await sleep(1000)" function I added to avoid lag, it fetches like 30 times, even then fetches 100 times then 300 times like its growing logarithmic which is really weird. When 5 minutes is passed it literally fetches every miliseconds and that cause the lag I guess.

Here is how I call functions and export them to use them:

```js
export const boughtRaffleTickets = async () => {
  const result = await rfflecontract.methods.boughtRaffleTickets(0).call();
  return result;
};
export const boughtRaffleTicketsByUser = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    try {
      const addressArray = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_accounts",
      });

      if (addressArray.length > 0) {
        const raffleID = "0";
        const result = await rfflecontract.methods.boughtRaffleTicketsByUser(window.ethereum.selectedAddress, raffleID).call();
        return result;
      } else {
        const networkmessage = "Go Rinkeby"
        return networkmessage;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return {
        address: "",
        status: "" + err.message,
      };
    }
  } 
};
```

Thats my Hero:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import {
  boughtRaffleTickets,   // 1 //
  boughtRaffleTicketsByUser,  // 2 //
} from "./web3service";
import { connectWallet } from "./web3service";

const App = () => {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [activeRafflestogo, setactiveRaffles] = useState(0);     // 1 //
  const [ticketuser, setticketuser] = useState(0);               // 2 //

  useEffect(() => {
    const prepare = async () => {
      await sleep(12000);
      setactiveRaffles(await boughtRaffleTickets());       // 1 //
      setticketuser(await boughtRaffleTicketsByUser());      // 2 //
      setWinnerAddress(await getWinnerStructure());
      const walletResponse = await getCurrentWalletConnected();
      setWalletAddress(walletResponse.address);
      addWalletListener();
    };
    prepare();
  });
  console.log(activeRafflestogo);
  console.log(ticketuser);
  
  //metamask////////////////////////
  const connectWalletPressed = async () => {
    const walletResponse = await connectWallet();
    setWalletAddress(walletResponse.address);
  };

  const getCurrentWalletConnected = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      try {
        const addressArray = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_accounts",
        });

        if (addressArray.length > 0) {
          setLoading(false);
          return {
            address: addressArray[0],
            status: "",
          };
        } else {
          setLoading(true);
          return {
            address: "",
            status: "",
          };
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setLoading(true);
        return {
          address: "",
          status: "" + err.message,
        };
      }
    } 
  };

  function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time)
    )
  }
  //metamask////////////////////////

  const addWalletListener = () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async (accounts) => {
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
          setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
        } else {
          setWalletAddress("");
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Return Part:

```js
return (
    <div >
      <div id='raffleinterface' className="nftrafflebuy">
        {
          loading ? <>
            <ReactLoading class='loadingbar' type="spinningBubbles" />
            <p class="loadwarn">
            (If you are connected, kindly wait about 10 seconds untill interface loaded.)             </p>
            <button onClick={connectWalletPressed} className="me-2 mt-3                                     navbarwalletbottom">
            Connect Your Wallet-Rinkeby-</button>
          </> :
            (
              <>
                {`${activeRafflestogo}` >= 3 ? (
                  <>
                    <p>Sold OUT!</p>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <p className='tcktamnt'>{`${activeRafflestogo}`}/3</p>
                    <p className='yourtickets'>Your Tickets: {`${ticketuser}`}</p>
                  </>
                )}
              </>
            )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here how my console looks:

[image: Actual Problem I guess]

Comment: Can you show the `return` part (render section) of your function/App please?

Comment: I added Return Part.

Comment: it fetches 50000 times cause you have everything in a single useEffect hook, spread it out in different hooks. That way when one hook fires, it won't call every function again.

Also your hook needs an empty array as a dependency otherwise it will keep fetching. useEffect(()=>{},[] <------------ you are missing this empty array);